# Socket header file missing from its path [C language]

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, header-files, gnu

I have downloaded GNU GCC Compiler from *https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/*. I recently started working with socket But the socket header file is missing from its path and other networking files such as `arpa/inet.h`, `netinet/in.h`. I don't know where this file should be... What I should do? I am using  Windows 11 home with x64 based intel processor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mingw uses the windows headers, not the unix ones.

Comment: @StephenNewell So, What should I do for using the socket header file in MinGW?

Comment: I haven't done socket programming on Windows in over a decade, so you'll have to do some research.  I want to say the header is `winsock32.h`, but I'm going entirely off memory.  I recall there's an init function that has to be called too, and some extra libraries to link against.

Comment: Do some web research on the matter, that is "networking on Windows"... Then, if you have a specific issue, please [edit] your question.